# Spring log request payload

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to log every incoming request data and payload(body). How to configure that in Spring Boot? And how to hide sensitive data like password in logs?

Is it possible to log the original 'raw' request body (e.g. JSON)?

Comment: use AOP and intercept all requests, then log the body as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use AOP (Aspect Oriented programming) and intercept all the requests and log the info you need. Also you can filter which kind of requests need to log. An example with Spring-Boot could be this code

If you want to skip some methods from the logging in the aspect you can add this:

Create an annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NoLogging {}


@Aspect
@Component
public class LogsAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventAspect.class);

    @Before("execution(* com.your.controller..*Controller.*(..)) && !@annotation(NoLogging)")
    public void beforeController(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        String packageName = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();
        String params = getArguments(joinPoint);
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        //Log here your message as you prefer
    }
}
```

And in any method from your Controllers, if you want to avoid the logging by aspects add the annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@NoLogging
public ModelAndView loginUser(){
    //actions
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to mark sensitive data like password and not to log them?

Comment: Sure, you can create an annotation, NotLogging, and add to the methods where you dont want to be logged. I can add the details to the response if you need it

Comment: Yes, please add. Thanks.

Comment: @Romper check the response and ask if you miss understand something

Comment: well, I want to not log a property from body, not the entire body

Comment: then if its in a specific method, you can create a custom annotation and add the logic to skip that property, or in the generic method check the method name, and skip the property.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, to log any incoming request should place at webserver level instead of application level. 
For example, you could turn on/off access_log at Nginx.

Comment: But in case with spring, I can annotate sensitive data like password and not to log that data, how to do that in webserver level?

Comment: You could mask sensitive information using http map module (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)
or read this blog: https://www.rstcloud.net/blog/30-how-to-hide-sensitive-post-data-in-nginx-log

Comment: but every time I modify application code I should check also server configuration, that is not good